# Explain the difference between Java *client* security concerns and *server* security concerns

Tags: java, security, jvm

I see a lot of Java CVE's related to running malicious applets - but I rarely see CVE's that affect the server side component of the JVM. Example: http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/exploit_java_cve_2012_4681_h.shtml

Can anyone explain the difference with examples or sources (maybe a list of server side vs client side cves?) comparing the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking you don't see many CVEs that affect the server side because the server side virtually never runs user provided code (or an attacker's code).  The vulnerabilities with server side are mostly failure to properly handle input, and issues with configuration, so not Java's fault.

The client side however (applets being a great example) has lots of CVEs because the user's local JVM is actually running byte code that was provided by the attacker.  Vulnerabilities in the JVM can then be triggered and exploited.  These same vulnerabilities are usually present on the server side, but they aren't accessible to attackers.

Another reason you don't see many server side CVEs is because most of the server side vulnerabilities are application/implementation specific, and only affect the one application.  There are [quite a few CVEs for big web apps like WordPress](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=wordpress), however.

Comment: Somehow I misread this and posted pretty much the same answer: the attacker of a server JVM can usually just provide data, while the attacker of a client JVM can usually run any code he desires.